# How to use parameters on the following method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, optimization, parameters

I just ran Visual Studio's Code analysis, they told me to use a parameterized query for the following line of code:

```
using(var DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SQL, connectionstring))
```

The complete method:

```
public static DataTable SelectAll(string SQL)
        {
            //create a string(connectionstring), filled with the connectionstring
            string connectionstring = "Data Source=" + LogicDatabase.Databasename + ";Version=3;Password=" + Settings.SQLiteDatabasePassword + ";";
            //create a new DataSet
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            //Give name to a SQLiteDataAdapter

            //Create a new SQLiteDataAdapter and fill it with the sql query, and path of the Database.
            using(var DA = new SQLiteDataAdapter(SQL, connectionstring))
            {
                //Clear the dataset, so we are sure it is empty, before storing items in it.
                DS.Clear();
                //fill the dataset from the SQLiteDataAdapter.
                DA.Fill(DS);
                //Fill the DataTable with the first table of the DataSet
                DataTable DT = DS.Tables[0];
                //return the DataTable
                return DT;
            }                 
        }
```

How can I implement parameters in this code?

Comment: What's your SQL statement?

Comment: The statement is variable, it can be a parameterized query, it can also be something like: select productid, productname from products

Comment: It can't be a parameterized query if you're just passing in a SQL statement.  You could change it to use a `SqlLiteCommand` instead (which you _can_ add parameters to.

Comment: Can I still return a DataTable that way?

Comment: Sure - logically it would be exactly the same.  I'll add an answer with more detail.

Comment: After some research it's not as simple as I anticipated to change from string SQL to a command - you need to add the connection to the command as well.  May not be worth the effort to get rid of a warning.  The _risk_ is in how you build your SQL statement to avoid SQL Injection attacks.  If you are careful with how you build your SQL you can probably safely ignore the warning.

Comment: I do use parameters when inserting, updating and deleting, I also checked if there was an easy way, but it seems there isn't thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SQLiteCommand` and fill it with your SQL statement. It has a property `Parameters` which you can fill with instances of `SQLiteParameter`. After that, you can use this command to create your `SQLiteDataAdapter`.